# using .then in cordova javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, asynchronous

I am new to Cordova and java script and I want to create a simple mob app that when you click a button the button will get the latitude printed on it -
index.js looks like this:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
    // 'pause', 'resume', etc.
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        document.getElementById("getPosition").addEventListener("click", getGPSPosition);


    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }

};
app.initialize();



function getGPSPosition()
{

    var positionText = '';
    getPosition(positionText).then(handletext(positionText),handleerror());

}
function handletext(positionText)
{
    alert('wtf');
    document.getElementById("getPosition").innerHTML = positionText;
    return positionText;
    //document.getElementById("getPosition").innerHTML = 'ok';
}
function handleerror()
    {
        alert('wtf2');
        document.getElementById("getPosition").innerHTML = 'error';
    }
```

the button appears fine and the location works fine, I just can't get the value to the button and am confused as hell by the ".then". The code in geolocation.js is here:

```
/**
 * Created by johannesgrobler on 06/12/2016.
 */
function getPosition(positionText)
{
    var options = {enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 3600000};

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
    function onSuccess(position){
        //return
        positionText = position.coords.latitude;
        alert(positionText);
    }
    function onError() {
        positionText = 'GeoLocation error';
        alert(positionText);

    }
    return positionText;

}
```

help please, its driving me nuts!!

Comment: You are returning a changed value of `positionText` before it's been set in the async call.

Comment: Thanks but can you highlight what I need to do? sorry, Im totally stuck.

Comment: What I mean is how did I set the positionText value only after the asynchronous call comes back?

Comment: I got it working by not using "done" at all but would really love if someone could show me how to make it work, I put alert into the functions and it's going into the right places at the right time but my problem is the variable I'm trying to fill out and pass back to the original place it was sent from...I'm guessing you can't do that. Perhaps what I'm trying is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like,

```
function getGPSPosition(){
  var positionText = '';

  new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var options = {enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 3600000};

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, options);

  })
  .then(onSuccess, onError)
  .then(handletext);

  function onSuccess(position){
      positionText = position.coords.latitude;
      alert(positionText);
  }
  function onError() {
      positionText = 'GeoLocation error';
      alert(positionText);
  }
  function handletext(positionText)
  {
      alert('wtf');
      document.getElementById("getPosition").innerHTML = positionText;
  }
}
```

I assume that all your functions are working.